# Installing PySerial 2.6 on Windows XP SP3

Tags: pyserial, windows-xp-sp3

Ok, I am trying to install PySerial 2.6 on my windows XP SP3 machine. After having unpacked the PySerial download and running the setup.py file I get this error.

```
C:\PYSERIAL\dist\pyserial-2.6\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PYSERIAL\dist\pyserial-2.6\setup.py", line 44, in <module>
    open(os.path.join('serial', '__init__.py')).read()).group(1)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'serial\\init_.py'
```

I don't see the problem. There is a file in the same directory as setup.py called 'serial' and

```
__init__.py
```

is inside that file. So whats going wrong? I'm sitting here looking at the file in the directory!

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
easy_install
```

and the url where the file was located, it was all taken care of automatically.